# Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found by my Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jaxb, java-11, tycho

I need to add XML-unmarshalling ability to my Eclipse RCP plugin. I'm using JAXB to work with XML-files. It all works great if I run RCP from my IDE. Then I build my plugin with `mvn clean package` and install it to my RCP with its UI. It all runs smoothly until I want my unmarshalling. In the code where I try to create JAXB context I get this exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:232)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:375)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
at my.code -skip-
```

The Internet told me that JAXB implementations were banned from JDK starting from Java-11. So, I need to add one to my build. Maven dependencies don't work for me because I'm dealing with Tycho. I decided to take `com.sun.xml.bind` artifact from [this location](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops2/R20210223232630/repository/plugins/com.sun.xml.bind_2.3.3.v20201118-1818.jar).
I put the ID of the artifact to my plugin's `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
-skip-
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.14.0",
 -skip-
 jakarta.xml.bind;bundle-version="2.3.3",
 com.sun.xml.bind;bundle-version="2.3.3"
-skip-
```

I've also added it to the target definition:

```xml
-skip-
  <unit id="com.sun.xml.bind" version="2.3.3.v20201118-1818"/>
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20201130205003/repository/"/>
-skip-
```

The environment:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault
```

I tried to set `javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.JAXBContextFactory` in `jaxb.properties`. Same result.
I tried another implementation from `org.eclipse.persistence` (Moxy). The result was the same (could not find `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`).

I can find those artifacts in my RCP application in the `plugins` folder. Why does not my plugin see them? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which artifacts are you referring to being in your RCP app's plugins folder? Shouldn't the API bundle also be in your target platform, not just the implementation?

Comment: I'm refering to these jars: `com.sun.xml.bind_2.3.3.v20201118-1818.jar` and `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041.jar`
Sure, the API bundle is there too. Otherwise I would not be able to use it my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my problem was in this line where I wanted to create the context:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(nodeClass);
```

It threw that `JAXBException` because it could not find any implementation. I haven't solved the problem but I have figured out I could use a brute force workaround that is quite ok for me. I've just replaced the line with this:

```
JAXBContext ctx = ContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { nodeClass }, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
```

Imports:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory;
```